# How to choose correct "scenario" when using Microsoft Cognitive Service (Bing Speech API, Speech to Text)?

Tags: bing, azure-cognitive-services

I found it seems have many scenarios support in Bing Speech API,
1. websearch
2. catsearch
3. smd
4. ulm

Are there any other scenarios support? and where can I find the documents
about how to choose scenario?

Thanks in advance